# jQuery - What's the error here?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm working with jQuery's .get() function and I'm having a very weird problem using it.

Here's the front end...

```
<body>

<button title="minor">Minor Armor</button>
<br /><br />
<button title="medium">Medium Armor</button>
<br /><br />
<button title="major">Major Armor</button>
<br /><br />
<center>
    <div id="printout" style="border: 1px black dotted; height: 300px; width: 300px;">
    </div>
</center>

</body>
```

Here's the function I'm trying to use...

```
$("button").click(function () {
            var v = "dnd_specific_armor_" + $(this).attr("title");
            alert(v + " was pressed.");
            $.get("randloot.php", { "table" : v }, function(data) {
                if(data.roll != 0) {    
                    alert(data.roll);
                    alert(data.armor);
                    alert(data.price);
                    $('#printout').text("Roll - " + data.roll
                                        "\nArmor - " + data.armor
                                        "\nPrice - " + data.price);
                }
                else
                    $('#printout').text("Oops");
            }, "json");
        });
```

The buttons simply will not respond to clicks.  The alert window does not pop up, I get nothing in my div box.  No response at all.

The funny thing though, is that if I take out the .get() portion and use just this...

```
$("button").click(function () {
            var v = "dnd_specific_armor_" + $(this).attr("title");
            alert(v + " was pressed.");             
        });
```

Then it works fine.

I'm trying to work within Firefox 4 and I've tried pulling up the Java Console (which doesn't even show) and the Error Console (which isn't reporting any errors).  So I can't figure out what's going wrong at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Get firebug and see what it shows.

Comment: You're missing `+` string concats on your `$('#printout').text` lines.

Comment: Rather than using `alert()` which is blocking, consider using `console.log()`. This will write to the Firebug console or Chrome JavaScript console. Not sure about other browser support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains syntax errors.

```
                $('#printout').text("Roll - " + data.roll
                                    "\nArmor - " + data.armor
                                    "\nPrice - " + data.price);
```

should be

```
                $('#printout').text("Roll - " + data.roll +
                                    "\nArmor - " + data.armor +
                                    "\nPrice - " + data.price);
```

Btw, checking the error console would have shown this, too - that's usually a good thing to do before asking here. ;)

Comment: 74% is fine, Its the <20% that I worry about :D